# multiple marked files in `dired-do-async-shell-command ` open seperate instances of app (picard)..how does one pass them as a list?

Tags: dired

So I'm trying to send a bunch of marked files to picard with dired's '&' (`dired-do-async-shell-command`).
In the normal command line this opens one instance of picard with all the selected files:

```
picard 01\ -\ Snail\ -\ Underwater.ogg 02\ -\ Alain\ Johannes\ -\ Kaleidoscope.ogg
```

But in dired when I mark a few files and issue `& picard` I get two instances of picard.

How does one make dired send all mark files into one picard instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the docstring of `dired-do-shell-command`, in particular this part:

```
If there is a ‘*’ in COMMAND, surrounded by whitespace, this runs
COMMAND just once with the entire file list substituted there.
```

This means you can run the command once just with `& picard * RET`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`w`** in Dired to copy the names of the marked files to the `kill-ring`, for later yanking (pasting).

Then, when you use a command such as `&` (`dired-do-async-shell-command`), you can yank that list of files into the shell command input where needed.

Comment: thx @drew. but what if the application is a GUI app (like picard)? the CLI example was when launching it from shell. if i understand your suggestion, you recommend running a shell after & and from there launching `picard FILE1 FILE2`. thx!  Z

Comment: Also: using this methodology you need to manually quote all spaces in each file name in the CLI right?

Comment: See Juri @link0ff's answer, which is a *much better* answer than mine. I knew there was a way to do that, but I'd forgotten what it was (`*`).

Comment: For quoting spaces etc. see function`shell-quote-argument`.